# Is there a check valve in the bathtub valve that would prevent water from going reversed through the valve?

Tags: bathtub

New single handled type shower tub faucet in a new house in Mexico. 250 gallon gravity fed tank on roof. Has boiler. Water comes out real slow. Appears when in cold position no water comes out, only hot water. I'm assuming it's clogged.

- Took off tub water inlet
- Connected small pump
- Shut off water supply
- Took off the cold water line from hot water heater inlet
- Turned on pump

No water comes out of the unhooked heater hose. Does this valve have a check valve built into the valve, which is not allowing water to go backwards through the valve?

Comment: What's the make and model of the valve?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain without checking it out in person, but I would be surprised to see a check valve in that line.

Comment: How do you know the water line doesn't have a check valve installed?

Comment: Extremely unlikely unless there was a specific reason for installing it. One more thing to maintain and usually no need.

Comment: With a gravity fed tank in mexico, it would imply a different installation than I'm used to working with. But I can imagine the scenario where they don't want water backfeeding in the system if pressure is lost for some reason.

Comment: ... granted. Rephrasing.